My first actual cryptic
My first attempt at making a cryptic crossword. All suggestions and feedback appreciated!




ACROSS
DOWN




1. Radar Two fabricates imminent bomb drop (3,4)
1. Writer is golden female Thor? (9)


6. Little French city, say (3)
2. Direction of sunshine (3)


7. For digestion aid: first try head-scratcher cryptic (7)
3. Picture this cryptic, if I have a high opinion of myself (3)


10. All are welcome to the result of 1A? (4,5)
4. Download a century of paid content (3)


11. Bomb ingredient originally née Taco (7)
5. Flat position seems like 1A, for example (5,4)


14. Respectfully said, I rushed at first (3)
8. Fear the people of cooking utensil? (5)


15. In Paris, it's said housing is given to the needy that's most quiet (7)
9. It carries Korean currency but I will not (1,4)



11. E.g. Frodo's journey is mostly just a circle (3)



12. Electrical engineer at large, could be a shocker (3)



13. 1A basically is a low score (3)





 

1 2nd radar fabricates imminent bomb drop (3,4)

 AIRRAID* (RADAR + II) -- The use of 2nd for II is questionable.

6 Little short French city, say

 LIL (L'IL as in L'IL Abner, LILLE, Homophone)

7 For digestion aid: first try head-scratcher cryptic

 T (Try first) + RYPTIC (head scratch cRYPTIC)

10 All are welcome to the result of 1A? (4,5)

 OPEN HOUSE dd? Don't like the second def very much...

11 Bomb ingredient originally née Taco

 ACETONE*

14 Respectfully said, I rushed at first

 S___ I R_____

15 Most peaceful French say housing is given to church (Pre Edit)

 CALMEST (no idea beyond "most peaceful")

15 In Paris, it's said housing is given to the needy that's most quiet (Post Edit)

 CALMEST In Paris "it's" = CEST housing (insert) ALM

DOWN
1 Writer is golden female Thor?

 AU + THOR + ESS -- Nice Clue!

2 Direction of sunshine

 RAY

3 Picture this cryptic, if I have a high opinion of myself

 ART dd Picture | this cryptic...

4 Content with your purchase?

 DLC (downloadable content) simple def.

5 Flat position in 1A, for example (5,4)

 PLANE (flat) SEAT

8 Fear the people of cooking utensil?

 PANIC  I think this is PAN + IC meaning "The people of PAN"

9 It carries Korean currency but I will not (1,4)

 I(WON)T

11 e.g. Frodo's journey is mostly just a circle

 ARC  (as in story ARC, part circle) dd

12 Fish!? Heard a very long sound of disgust

 EEL ( not sure)

13 1A basically is a low score

 ONE dd.


Thanks for feedback! Regarding 15a, intended wordplay is (rot13) "Serapu fnl" -> "P'RFG" (ubzbalz), "Vf tvira gb puhepu" -> "NYZ", gurersber "PRFG" ubhfvat "NYZ" tvirf "PNYZRFG", and for 12d, intended word play is (rot13) "Irel ybat fbhaq bs qvfthfg" -> "rjjjjjjjjjj", fbhaqnyvxr sbe "rry". I was trying to make 4d a dd as well ("content" and "your purchase") but the surface reading is already too obvious :/

Ok, I was interpreting "French say" as "DIT" (or other conjugation).   I'm not sure I like the double use of say as both the homophone indicator and the fodder.

12d -  Doesn't work in my accent!

Hmm, thanks for the additional feedback! I'll workshop the clues a bit, I think "French speakers say housing..." removes "say" from double duty...

If you accept a second opinion: The "French say" thing doesn't work for me either, even after your edit. rot13("P'rfg" xvaqn fbhaqf yvxr "fnl" (ohg vg ernyyl qbrfa'g sbe zr), ohg V qba'g guvax lbh pna pyhr vg jvgu "Serapu fnl", juvpu gb zr rvgure zrnaf n Serapu jbeq gung zrnaf "fnl" yvxr qver be qvf be vg zrnaf Serapu nf na rknzcyr (sbe  n ynathntr be n angvba, fnl). Vs lbh jnag gb pyhr "p'rfg", lbh pbhyq hfr "Vg'f Serapu" be "Vg'f va Serapu" be "Va Cnevf, vg'f": pyhr gur zrnavat, abg n Serapu ubzbcubar. Naq nyzf ner tvira gb gur arrql, abg gb gur puhepu.)

But good on you for creating this crossword with a good grid. I've seen that you've rewritten the clue for 2D. It's discouraged to do that, because it renders Chris's answer obsolete. I know, it's just one clue, so no sweat here. Why not incorporate the feedback you got into a fresh crossword? :)

I took another shot at 15a. I understand that changing the clues is discouraged, but from my perspective, I don't want to leave a crossword in a subpar state, as this crossword is now on the internet and I don't know who may end up reading it in the future
